# How to create 8 characters long ID with 4 letters and 4 numbers (for example AABB0011)

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to create the unique ID and It must be eight characters long and consist of four letters and four numbers (for example AABB0011)

There is the table I've created:

```
create table departments(
DepartmentID varchar(8) not null,
Duty varchar(100),
Budget int,
StartDate date,
primary key (DepartmentID)
);
```

I want `DepartmenID` to have 4 letters and 4 number, but I understand that it's impossible to use `auto_increment` with `varchar` datatype.

Comment: See linked answer, the solution is pretty much the same in MySQL. Use a computed column to calculate the 4 letters using arithmetic.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422806/how-to-enable-auto-increment-in-lettersa-b-c-d-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: no good ways to do this.  in mysql (answer is different for mariadb), because you cannot refer to an auto increment column in a generated column and there are no true sequences, the best way to do this is to emulate a sequence: have a separate department_ids table containing only a bigint auto increment key; insert into that to generate the int id, then in your code (either client side or stored procedure) change that to a new alphanumeric id and insert into your departments table.